# Need to check a particular key value in my Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am working in an application need to check a particular key value I will paste my JSON response of `[[String: Any]]` type. but I could not check it or else could not fetch the status key from the array.

```
[
    {
        "updated_by": <null>, 
        "created_at": 2018-12-26T07:28:04.000Z, 
        "deleted_by": <null>, 
        "status": Request, 
        "friend_id": 139,
        "user_id": 141, 
        "id": 53, 
        "created_by": 141, 
        "deleted_at": <null>, 
        "is_deleted": 0, 
        "updated_at": <null>
    }
]
```

I need to take "status": Request this field alone from the response and I need to check it.

For example:

```
if status == "Request"{
    //need to do some task
} else {
    //need to do some
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw in another solution, using `filter` to find the desired status:

```
let requests = array.filter { $0["status"] as? String == "Request" }})
```

Where `requests` will contain any `status == "Request"` requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through items:

```
for dictionary in dict {
    if let status = dictionary["status"] as? String, status == "Request" {
        // Status is found
    } else {
        // Not found
    }
}
```